# d3.js date time format specifier not working as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the below format specifier for dealing with datetime inputs in my d3.js force directed graph

```
    var parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Below is an example of how the datetime data is in my graph. But

```
    console.log(parseDate('2015-1-7 13:45:54'))
```

gives the following output:

```
 0NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN:NaN
```

Is there anything additional that needs to be done with the input?

Link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/6x5Ly6tn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a Date object to the `parseDate` function:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

// method 1 (month is zero-based)
console.log(parseDate(new Date(2015, 0, 7, 13, 45, 54)));

// method 2
console.log(parseDate(new Date('2015-1-7 13:45:54')));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tudorciotlos/vd8fngyn/2/)

Comment: Hi when I check the console.log(parseDate(new Date(2015, 1, 7, 13, 45, 54)));
The output is 2015-02-07 13:45:54

Comment: @optimus_prime Isn't that the desired output?

Comment: Desired output should be 2015-1-07 13:45:54 right? It skips a month for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the month is zero-based. Please check my updated answer. You can also pass a date string when instantiating a Date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is `d3.timeParse()`

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

console.log(parseDate('2015-1-7 13:45:54'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [timeParse](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#timeParse) or [utcParse](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#utcFormat)

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

var parseDate = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x5Ly6tn/4/)